# We are unable save setting in CF Admin using the ColdFusion(2018) administrator window

Tags: coldfusion

We are getting below message in error log:

```
"There was an error while verifying the token. Either the session timed out or un-authenticated access is suspected."
```

When ever we are trying to update any setting or create new scheduler/gateway, it is redirecting us to login page.

Error While Updating any setting in CF Admin

Comment: Try using your browser in incognito mode.

Comment: In addition to what Adrian says, perhaps clear yer CFTOKEN / CFID / SESSIONID / JSESSIONID (and is there a specific one for CFAdmin auth? Cannae remember) cookies for the domain you are hitting CFAdmin from. I've had this sort of thing where I've somehow got a - eg - `CFTOKEN` and a `cftoken` cookie somehow. Clearing the CF-specific cookies usually fixes this sort of thing.